# Relating functions - Calculus

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I had been through this [lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-005-highlights-of-calculus-spring-2010/highlights_of_calculus/big-picture-of-calculus/) from an MIT open course ware.

Basic theme of this lecture is to explain the big picture of calculus, which is nothing but, relating functions.

In specific, below function `f1`(`distance` vs `time`) is being depicted(drawn) from the given behaviour of `f2`(`speed` vs `time`).

### [image]

My question:

As per function `f2`, I understand that the vehicle is moving with an accelerated speed. In function `f1`, I would like to understand, How is the initial value of distance close to zero(as highlighted above)?

Comment: The distance the vehicle has moved before it has moved at all must be $0$. What do you mean?

Comment: @Regret If my question looks stupid, sorry about that. But I would like to understand, In `f1`, why the graph is not having a positive slope(looks closely parallel to x-axis)  when t is close to zero?

Answer (score 0):

The graph could have been displayed better. From the speed-vs-time graph we can see that there is a linear relationship, namely
$$s=s_0+at,$$
where $s$ is the speed, $s_0$ is the initial speed (the speed at tinme $t=0$), and $a$ is the acceleration. If we integrate this with respect to time we get
$$x=\int(s_0+at) \ dt=\left(s_0x+\frac{1}{2}at^2\right)+c.$$
This is the expression for distance (we know this because the derivative of distance with respect to time is the speed or velocity), and we can see that it is a quadratic equation, and hence the curve is a parabola.

From his graph for distance v time, it passes through $(0,0)$, and all this means is that at time $t=0$ the distance of the object from the origin is $x=0$.

Comment: To be simpler, I think we can find area in graph `f2` at any point `t`. That would give the same results. Because linear algebra(without going to calculus) would suffice for above graph  `f2` as `f2`is constant in nature.

Comment: Finding the area under the speed graph is what I had done with the integration.

Comment: what am trying to say is, simple formulae `(1/2*base*height)`  would suffice for finding area. If the graph `f2` was not "constant in nature", then I would have gone for integration. The "varying nature" of a function actually triggers for the need of calculus. And vice verca for the usage of derivative calculus, I mean we just need to find `up/across` to get speed graph if the distance graph is constant in nature(unlike above `f1`).

Comment: Yes, in this case its a regular shape, so actual calculus is not necessary, but the result is the same.

Comment: Another beauty is, `f1` shows an accumulation of distance at time `t`, where as `f2` talks about speed at every instance of `t`.